# POST a form select id, AND value. The SELECT dropdown is created from a query loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, select

I am trying to POST a form select drop down that was created by a MySQL query.  The problem is I need to get the VALUE and ID.  I create the dropdown from a DB.  I am using the Value for JS calculations in the form prior to submitting doUpdate().  I want to use the ID for the description on the next page.  I originally used JS option=document.getElementById but I would like to avoid JS for this as the ID is generated by the query.

```
$query = 'select * from configurator where category = "SLK"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo'<select name="qtyG" id="SLK" onchange="doUpdate()">';
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '<option value="';
echo $row['price'];
echo '" ';
echo 'id="';
echo $row['description'];
echo '">';
echo $row['description'];
echo '</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

Again, the doUpdate is doing a calculation for pricing totals, then posting the value into the db.  I would also like to create a POST for the id, which I am using the description twice.  The problem with getElementById is you have to manually type on a JS page what the id is.

I am pretty sure I will have to use JS, I am asking for help specifically on how to get the id into a hidden input on the same form page.

Here is the JS I have started to create, but I just want the selected id to show up in a hidden input.  FYI, Yes my code is old, I havent programmed for 10 years and am just getting back into it.

```
function changeDescription(){
var option=document.getElementById('SLK').value;

if(option=="A")
{
        document.getElementById('field').value="A Selected";
}
    else if(option=="B"){
        document.getElementById('field').value="B Selected";
}
}
```

I dont want to use the if.  I just want to update the hidden input with the selected id value.

```
<input type ='text' name="SLK" id ="SLK"/>
```

By using the if option method, I have to manually update the JS code every time the DB info changes as pricing of descriptions.

I hope I am making sense.  I am not getting email notifications when you reply, unless it is going to Spam and I am not finding it. Your help is appreciated.

UPDATE WITH RESOLUTION

Thanks to Kiran for the help.  Here is the code I used to resolve the problem.  I output it to an input.

```
function changeDescription()
{
var select = document.getElementById('SLK');
if(select.selectedIndex >= 0) 
{
/* OK, the user selected an option, or we pre-selected one */
var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
/* now option refers to the select option element */
document.getElementById('SLKfield').value=option['id'];
}
}

<input type ='hidden' name="SLKoption" id ="SLKfield" size="40" />
```

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: Are you familiar with jquery??...something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/dVP43/

Comment: I agree, the while would work better.  I was cutting and pasting from other code.  I will update it.  reading your other reply now.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery, but will check out the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but I do not see the need to get the option elements by id. Instead, use the `select` element to find the value (and id) of the selected option. In your example, the select element has an id of `SLK`. To see if any option is selected, you can check the `selectedIndex` property. E.g.

```
var select = document.getElementById('SLK');
if(select.selectedIndex >= 0) {
   /* OK, the user selected an option, or we pre-selected one */
   var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
   /* now option refers to the select option element */
   alert('The id of the selected option is:' + option['id']);
   alert('The value of the selected option is:' + option.value);
}
```

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Kiran, thank you for this. This is what I used to resolve my problem. I changed it from alert to print to an input.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped solve your problem, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your PHP like this

```
<?php
$query = 'select * from configurator where category = "SLK"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="qtyG" id="SLK" onchange="doUpdate()">
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    <option value="<?=$row['price']?>"><?=$row['description']?></option>
}?>
</select>
```

and Javascript function

```
function changeDescription(){
var option=document.getElementById('SLK').value;
var sh_value=option+' Selected'
document.getElementById('field').value=sh_value;
}
```

Comment: I am unable to get this working.  I need to get the row[description] into a POST somehow.  In addition to the row[price].  The value of the select is row[price].  I need to POST both data somehow.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: In cases like this, its easier to put the value as id of the table instead of price. Post the id to the other page and query sql using where clause there. I cant say whats your requirement without seeing rest of the code